# VueJS conditional class in template

Tags: vue.js

I have this template that renders cards of each individual projects. These projects are being pulled from Firebase and stored in an array

```
<template>
    <div class="projects-wrapper">
         <div class="individual-project"
         v-bind:key="project.id" 
         v-for="project in projectsCollection" 
         :title="project.title" 
         >
            <Project :project="project" 
            v-on:update-likes="updateLikes" 
            v-on:expand-card="expandCard"
            v-on:close-card="closeCard" />

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Project from './Project'

export default {
    name: 'Projects',
    data() {
        return {
            projectsCollection: [],
        }
    },
```

I need to implement a functionality of resizing the card (in this example it is "individual-project" div) based on `project` key's value.
Now, I cannot just use `:class="expanded-class, isExpanded"` where isExpanded is a key in the `project` because I need to iterate through array (projectsCollection) and then iterate through an object to get this value.
Hence template does not see this key and fails to apply the class.

How would one approach this task? I am pretty new to Vue, so trying to figure things on the fly.

Comment: you could use a computed value?  or if it's `project.id` that determines which one is expanded `class={isExpanded: project.id == propwithExpandedId}`.  Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here.  Will probably need to know what object holds the "expanded" value and how it relates to the `key` (which is also unclear as to which key you are referring to), as well as how they are being passed into your Vue component.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What you posted so far is not sufficient to reproduce what you're describing. Make it minimal (only include what's strictly necessary to reproduce the issue) and, if you need a multi-file node based environment, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate the collection as you have access to each individual project.

You can use the property directly on your div:

```
<template>
    <div class="projects-wrapper">
         <div class="individual-project"
         v-bind:key="project.id" 
         v-for="project in projectsCollection" 
         :title="project.title"
         :class="{'expanded-class': project.isExpanded}"
         >
            <Project :project="project" 
            v-on:update-likes="updateLikes" 
            v-on:expand-card="expandCard"
            v-on:close-card="closeCard" />

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, because I cannot access project.isExpanded key in the template as it is stored in the array.

Comment: @Oleg, you are inside a loop (`v-for`). `project` is the iterated item and you have access to anything inside it.

Comment: @Oleg, if you're wondering if `project` is available on the `v-for` item (as opposed to only on its inner contents): ***yes, it is***. Try it!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because there is another iteration needs to happen. Because this iteration just returns an object that is in itself contains another object. This is the way Firebase is feeding me this objects.
Object {"Unique ID": {"key1": "value", "key2": "value", "key3": "value" }}

Comment: So when I pass this "project" to child, each child does another iteration before displaying this to the webpage.
It is probably should have been done better in terms of receiving the object from Firebase...

Comment: You could also access the property from the parent. In a way that makes more sense.